# GitHub private release asset browser download URL returns HTTP 404 when accessed with Personal Access Token

Tags: github, github-api

I have a personal access token that is has Read-only access to Releases in a repository.

[image]

I tried using Curl with the access token bearer like below

```
RELEASE_JSON=$(curl -L \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
      -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
      $API_BASE_URL/releases/latest)
```

And then I obtain the download URL for one of the asset files.

```
DOWNLOAD_URL=$(echo $RELEASE_JSON | 
    jq -r '.assets[] | 
        select(.name | contains("api.yaml")) | .browser_download_url')
```

It returns a URL correctly. I tried opening the URL in the browser and successfully download the file.

Now I want to download it using CLI to automate some process.

```
TEMP_FILE=$(mktemp).yaml
curl \
    -o $TEMP_FILE \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    $DOWNLOAD_URL
```

When I tried opening the file using `cat $TEMP_FILE`, the content is `Not Found`.

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried using wget

```
wget \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    $DOWNLOAD_URL -O $TEMP_FILE
```

it still returns 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to use the asset `url` instead of the `browser_download_url`. And I need to use header `Accept: application/octet-stream`.

This works

```
RELEASE_JSON=$(curl -L \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
      -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
      $API_BASE_URL/releases/latest)

DOWNLOAD_URL=$(echo $RELEASE_JSON | 
    jq -r '.assets[] | 
        select(.name | contains("api.yaml")) | .url')

TEMP_FILE=$(mktemp).yaml

echo "Downloading $DOWNLOAD_URL to $TEMP_FILE"
curl -L \
      -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
      -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
        $DOWNLOAD_URL > $TEMP_FILE
```